# Async await sqlite in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite

I have a problem about sync in sqlite so I tried to add async but nothing happened.
How to add async await to sqlite or make new promise with sqlite in react native.

I tried this and it was wrong

```
  async function getDate() {
     
    db.transaction(tx => {
          tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM dateTime where id=?',[1], async (tx, results) => {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            if (len > 0) {
              const a=await results.rows.item(0).date;//There will be an async function for setting like that
              setDate(a); 
            } else {
              console.log('>>>>>tarih yok');
            }
          });
     });
    
  }
```

Comment: `setDate` doesn't return a promise so you can't await for it

Comment: Right . Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Async/await doesn't do code `SYNC` it is just syntax sugar for Promises.
Working with DB async by its nature because you make a request to an external resource and wait for it.
You should think about your logic when you call `getDate`. For example:

```js
function getDate() {
     db.transaction(tx => {
          tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM dateTime where id=?',[1], async (tx, results) => {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            if (len > 0) {
              const a = results.rows.item(0).date;//There will be an async function for setting like that
              return Promise.resolve(a)
            } else {
              return Promise.reject('error')
            }
          });
     });
}
```

Next somewhere in your app:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true)
  getDate().then((result) => setData(result)).finally(() => {setIsLoading(false)})
}, [])
```

Comment: Using Promise makes sense, yes, but is it the correct usage? Because when I used your code exactly it didn't work properly. So I wrapped the return with `Promise((resolve, reject) => {}` and used the `then` solved it.